# How i division the text from 5 textboxes in 16 boxes characters

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hello I have a quiz game in android studio and I wanna make my life easier,so I create a form in visual studio to do all the job.

[image: FormImage]

I give to them 5 questions and 5 answers and I wanna take from program the 5 answers(only the answers) /16 boxes in random position inside..

```
something like this figure:
{"", "", "", "","","", "", "", "","","", "", "", "","","",},
```

Comment: Its not quite clear what you are asking. Are you trying to randomize or shuffle the order of items in a list?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Good question Sam I am, wait I am Sam?

Comment: i wanna shuffle the order of items and then /16 boxes like i figure..

Comment: Well first I would show what code you have or I fear the downvotes might be coming. Second look into the fisher yates shuffle great way to shuffle a list.

Comment: What "items" are you talking about? Please show the code (form image isn't really needed for this question). It's not clear how you're populating any questions, or what the relationship between a question and an answer is (i.e. do you have a `QuizItem` class that has both `Question` and `Answer` properties? Are you using two arrays? How are you loading the question/answer pairs?

Answer (score 0):

this code convert my questions ready

textBox11->Text = "{\042"+ textBox1->Text +"\042,"+ "\042" + textBox2->Text +"\042," + "\042" + textBox3->Text +"\042," +"\042"+ textBox4->Text +"\042," + "\042"+   textBox5->Text +"\042"+"},";

and the result is: {"1","2","3","4","5"}, (where 1,2,3,4,5 the 5 questions)

i want the same for anwsers but shuffled and div to 16 not to 5.
like this: {"", "", "", "","","", "", "", "","","", "", "", "","","",},
inside the " "characters from(5 anwsers) shuffled.. :D